# enable schedule task from windows 2008

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to enable and disable a schedule task on windows server 2003 R2 from windows server 2008 R2 machine.
I am also using username and password. Error given Access is denied.
Following is the command
`schtasks /change /disable /tn <taskname> /s <remoteserver 2003R2>  /RU <username> /RP <password>`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with user for running the schedule task. Added the user to the admin group. Issue resolved.